# Ошибка при интеграции Unity Monetization

Tags: unity3d

Ошибка (Когда импортирую Ассет от Unity - Unity Monetization ) :

```
PrecompiledAssemblyException: Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor.dll included for the current platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per platform. Assembly path: {0}
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorBuildRules.CreateTargetAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] customScriptAssemblies, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] precompiledAssemblies) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorBuildRules.cs:249)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.UpdateCustomTargetAssemblies () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:619)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.SetAllCustomScriptAssemblyJsons (System.String[] paths) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:728)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.SetAllCustomScriptAssemblyJsons (System.String[] allAssemblyJsons) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilationInterface.cs:217)
```

Вроде, сами разработчики Юнити об этом знают , но я так и не смог решить эту проблему.

Кстати , скорее всего эта ошибка появляется из-за одинаковых файлов.

Comment: так это у вас вопрос или вы нашли решение?

Comment: @ Alt_F4 Тогда был вопрос. Уже смог найти решение , но забыл добавить ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Нажмите для просмотра ответа (ссылка на ответ)](https://forum.unity.com/threads/upgrading-to-2018-3-with-unity-ads-sdk.601132/)